# How can I use Express and EJS to serve static and dynamic content?

Tags: node.js

I want to build a simple app using node.js that 'functions' like IIS/classic ASP where all the content (html, png, js, css, ejs) can be in one directory and the ejs file uses javascript vs. VBScript.

I've gathered the following from API's and other examples, but the ejs file arrives at the browser as a binary and gets saved....

My node.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/html')); 
app.engine('.ejs', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/html');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('*.ejs', function(req, res) {
   res.render(__dirname + '/html' + req.url, function(err, result) {
      res.end(result);
   });
});
app.listen(8080);
```

My test.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head><title>A test</title></head>
   <body>
     My Test Page
       <% if (1==1) { %>
          Working
       <%}%>
   </body>
</html>​
```

What am I missing or where can I find a working example?

**I FIGURED IT OUT... SOLUTION ADDED ABOVE**

Comment: Set content type "application/json"?

Comment: Middleware works in order. See if moving your `static` to the last line before `app.listen(8080)` works for you.

Comment: @barry-johnson, rearranging still gets a downloaded file.

Comment: @shaun5 Great that you found a solution, but it'd be better if you rolled back your original post to show what the question was, and then either a) posted your solution as an answer or b) accepted the existing answer.  As it is now, this is unlikely to help anyone else who had a similar question.

Answer (score 4):

express.js won't magically try to render static files, you have to explicitly call `render` somewhere.

I believe something like this would work:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.engine('.ejs', require('ejs').__express)
app.set('views', __dirname + '/html')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(app.router) // only in express 3, remove that in express 4
app.get('/test.html', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('test.ejs')
})
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/html'))
app.listen(8080)
```

Comment: This only renders test.html as test.ejs.

Comment: Of course it does, you need to use placeholders in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe is not necessary to run render in every place, I use this example to render my static content by migrating express 2.3.7 to 4 and works fine with :

```
app.engine('.ejs', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

My static content is in 'public' directory.

Answer (score -1):

I just want to add that express supports EJS out of the box these days:

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Answer (score -1):

I have made a npm module that can run render engines with a static server, check out [express-static-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-static-plus)

it supports ejs, jade, mustache, dust, nunjucks and pug

```js
var staticPlus = require('express-static-plus')

var express = require('express')

var app = express()

app.use(staticPlus(__dirname+'/test',{passed_data:"hello world"}))

app.listen(8080)
```